# How can I completely reverse all changes by npm in Ubuntu

Tags: nodejs

The Question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x but for Ubuntu, and mainly concerns the cleanup part.

Installation was done as usual by: `sudo apt-get install node`, however I later used the `npm` command to install multiple packages as more than one users.

How do I completely remove npm along with all libraries, packages and any other files installed by npm on my system by e.g. `npm install -g @vue/cli`? I would probably have to uninstall from `apt`, but the main question has to do with all the changes `npm` did.

Notes:

1. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS npm version 7.5.6 if that matters
2. As there seems to be some fights about people uninstalling npm going on currently, please do not downvote just because I want to uninstall, I plan to reinstall :)

Edit-Reminder to future self and others:
For reinstalling without sudo , [a link with recipes can be found here](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814). It is still unclear to me what's best but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081293/install-npm-into-home-directory-with-distribution-nodejs-package-ubuntu on the other hand there is [README.md#debinstall](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall) so possibly [use apt to install node, then use prefix](https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be messy ...

The simplest solution that I have found to this problem when trying to "fix" a broken development server that couldn't be formatted and rebuilt from scratch due to "management" is this:

1. remove the globally installed packages
2. delete the locally installed packages from the various `/home` directories and `/root`
3. remove Node

Here's the basic process:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open) or SSH into the machine (if you don't have physical access)
1. List all globally installed packages:

   ```
   npm list -g --depth 0
   ```
2. Uninstall the global packages one by one with:

   ```
   sudo npm uninstall -g <package-name>
   ```

   If you'd like to also do this for locally installed packages from your account, you can do this:

   ```
   npm list
   npm uninstall -S <package-name>
   ```

   The `-S` flag will also remove the reference in your `package.json` file
3. Remove the following directories:
   ⇢ `/etc/npmrc`
   ⇢ `/home/youruser/.npmrc`
   ⇢ `/root/.npmrc`
   ⇢ `./.npmrc` in any project directory next to `package.json` (search by using `locate .npmrc`)
4. Remove the Node package:

   ```
   sudo apt remove nodejs --purge  
   sudo apt remove npm --purge
   ```
5. Finally, remove the straggling files and directories:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm \ 
               /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* \
               /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d \
               ~/.npm \
               ~/.node-gyp \
               /opt/local/bin/node \
               /opt/local/include/node \
               /opt/local/lib/node_modules
   ```

   ... and the modules:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
   ```

   ... and the include modules:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
   ```

   ... and the files in the local `/bin`:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
   ```
6. Enjoy a 15-minute break, because you're done

At this point, you can reinstall Node and its package manager if you wish to start over with a clean slate.

Answer (score 2):

The command I use to remove all packages from npm is..

```
npm ls -gp --depth=0 | awk -F/ '/node_modules/ && !/\/npm$/ {print $NF}' | xargs npm -g rm
```

Failing that (and sometimes npm can get very clingy)..

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/node_modules
rm -rf ~/.npm*
```